# Best place to put event listener in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, events, state

In my project I have a main .as which defines a class.

In the class I have various other objects as members. One of them contains information about the state of the app, I inject this in to other classes so they all know what's going on.

The state class also dispatches a custom event when things change.

My question is, is it bad to do something like this:

```
public class SomeClass {

    private var appState:AppState;

    public function SomeClass(appState:AppState) {
        this.appState = appState;
        this.appState.addEventListener(AppState.INFO_UPDATE, this.appStateUpdated);
    }

    private function appStateUpdated(e:Event) {
        //do something with new appstate
    }

}
```

I like this way, but I'm not sure if it'll come back to bite me later. Is this an OK way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the event system as such is more or less creating the observer pattern.
(That is, one object observes changes in another object)

Based on the observer pattern is the MVC pattern, which is the base of pretty much every application in one way or another.

A part of that is V, the `view`, which observes M, the `model` for changes.
In your case, `appState` could be the `model` and `SomeClass` could be a `view` (a class thereof). In order to observe the `model`, the `view` receives a reference to the `model` object. This is often done exactly the way you do it.

Please keep in mind that you should never force any pattern. The point of the above is to tell you that passing an observable to a class like that is very common to happen. However, that doesn't mean it's necessarily the right choice in your situation. (it very likely is the right choice, just don't think doing this is per se the right choice)

Don't forget to clear the reference to `appState` when destroying a `SomeClass` object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use callbacks instead of eventListeners, it will be faster.

In your AppState class you will set up an array to save the callback functions, and call them when updated.

```
public class AppState 
{
    private var callbacks:Array = [];

    public function addCallback(update:function):void
    {
    }

    public function removeCallback(update:function):void
    {
    }

    public function update():void
    {
        for each (var callback:Function in callbacks)
        {
             callback.apply(null, [//maybe some param here]);
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: My question was more about setting up the event listener IN the class. If I did it with callbacks. in my SomeClass, I would still need something like AppState.addCallback(whatever); That's what I'm asking about - whether or not specifying the callback or event or whatever INSIDE the class concerned is a bad idea.